# New "more" command form feeds before every file: how to suppress?

Tags: text-processing, more, util-linux

For 35 years I've been watching the `more` command work like this: when specifying multiple files, and without any options, it displays a header and the file contents as follows (most easily seen for short files):

```
$ more file*
::::::::::::::
file1
::::::::::::::
one
/* you press the space bar to advance from this point */
::::::::::::::
file2
::::::::::::::
two
/* you don't press it here because it's already reached EOF */
$
```

The above is with `more` from `util-linux` version `2.37.2` as on Ubuntu 22.04.  With the new `util-linux 2.38` as on Ubuntu 22.10, it prints a terminal "form feed" before every file header (apparently before each `::::::::::::::`) and drives all previous output off the screen: for me, defeating the purpose of a text file browser.

Also with `more` version 2.38 it is now apparently mandatory to advance to the next file by entering `:n` as one would in `vi`.  This is somewhat natural for me as a `vi` user, but also disturbing because it used to be possible to use the space bar alone to advance continuously through all files.

`more --help` as always shows some options to control pagination, but as far as I can tell (at least as compiled on Ubuntu) the form feeding has been introduced without any options to suppress it.

Even if possible to pin back `util-linux` version `2.37.2`, I don't see that's sustainable because it would also halt development of 100+ other Unix commands which have been part of the standard vocabulary for decades.  The implications of changing how `more` has worked since the 1980's are too far-reaching that they must have been considered: i.e. some means of restoring the original behaviour.

Comment: `ls` got broken^H^H^H^H^H^H^H changed, so I'd say it was quite possible behaviour has also been changed

Comment: Does it work as before if you invoke it with `-e` that is `more -e file1 file2 etc`?

Comment: thanks @don_crissti that is precisely the answer.  I never would have guessed the quoted description "exit on end-of-file" would be applicable to this behaviour.  Not the only thing I've seen strangely documented in Unix in 35 years, so no worries.  If you'd like to write up the short solution I'll mark it as the answer: if I can see that hasn't happened by tomorrow then I will do this myself.

Comment: rphair - it looks like it's not the end of story... please read my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the newly introduced option

```
-e, --exit-on-eof
    Exit on End-Of-File, enabled by default if not executed on terminal.
```

Apparently, [it was done for POSIX compliance, i.e. to prevent exit on EOF without `-e`](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/commit/df6b29d3b8e9a55d2bfa69c593e17da4d11a3fac).
HOWEVER, because a lot of people have already complained that this breaks backward compatibility (and in order to fix it they have to `alias more='more -e'`) another change is in the pipeline - one that will revert the old behavior and [enable `-e` by default **if** `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable is not set or if not executed on terminal](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/commit/28b391ce7e58f8327c092b3911c05f526d0ad586). So probably in the next release, the behavior that you've been used to will be back (as long as `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not set).

Comment: Thanks for including the history: now as long as today's `more -e` will be forward compatible with the upcoming restored version of `more` then with a shell alias we'll never have to worry about this again :|

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is of use, but I've taken to use `| tail -n+1 | more` instead of just `| more` (or `|less` for that matter).

try it with something like:

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs tail -n+1 | more
```

The nice bit about this is you get a header also at the top of each file, with the filename in it too boot. Something like:

```
...
==> ./somefile.name <==
...
```